# Is there a function that can send event to other window in pygtk or other libry

Tags: python, pygtk, xlib

I am trying to write a application that can control other windows such as `terminal` on `linux`. I found that the send_event function of `xlib` can do this but `xlib` is an low-level API for the X window server that not very easy to use.

I've read the api of `PyGTK` and know it is based on `xlib`, but I didn't find a function like `send_event`,maybe I missed it. Is there a function that can send `event` to other window in `PyGTK` or other library?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the window id, you can do this:

```
from gtk import gdk

window = gdk.window_foreign_new(0x...) # Replace ... with the hexadecimal ID
window.move(0, 0) # Moves window to the top-left corner
window.fullscreen()
```

Have fun!